# Multiple Xorg processes running on both GPUs

Tags: ubuntu, gpu

The following behavior has not been typical in the past.  I have two GPUs on a Ubuntu 18.04 system: one for a two-monitor display and one for GPU computations.  On boot, I never have seen processes on my compute GPU. Recently, I noticed multiple Xorg processes run, 2 on each my two GPUs.  I also see gnome-shell running two processes.  Is this is a problem, and how can it be fixed?

(I'm investigating this as part of understanding why I cannot use my compute GPU for computations after a suspend.)

```
$ nvidia-smi
Tue Aug 18 11:05:47 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06    Driver Version: 450.51.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN RTX           On   | 00000000:1A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 41%   34C    P8    10W / 280W |     11MiB / 24220MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce RTX 207...  On   | 00000000:68:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 22%   40C    P5    15W / 215W |    811MiB /  7979MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2038      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5566      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      2038      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 73MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      2078      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              178MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      5566      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                481MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      5740      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               33MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     23000      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       41MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Not yet -- maybe not enough votes to get attention.

Comment: After chatting with NVIDIA support it was recommended to update the NVIDIA driver (as of today 460.32.03) and doing so the problem went away.

Comment: Same here. Running Kubuntu on a laptop with only one GTX 1050 GPU. OBS nvenc encoder stops working after a suspend,

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem, ubuntu 20.04, two GPUs , Tesla and GTX cards, probably not relevant since I assume it would apply to any GPU configuration and my intention was to use the GTX GPU for video output and dedicate the Tesla GPU for CUDA only.
I tried multiple things and I recommend you look into the nvidia xorg documentation ( https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/460.67/README/xconfigoptions.html ) and xorg documentation ( https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/xserver-xorg-core/xorg.conf.5.en.html) to understand their purpose.

My recommendation is to **first** use the `nvidia-xconfig` tool to create the basic xorg.conf file (e.g. `sudo nvidia-xconfig -a` ) and then modify/edit as per below.

Some relevant changes:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
  (...)
  Option "AutoAddGPU" "false"
EndSection
```

> Option "AutoAddGPU" "boolean"   If this option is disabled, then no
> GPU devices will be added from the udev backend. Enabled by default.
> (May need to be disabled to setup Xinerama).

Using `lspci` I found the PCI id for both cards, in my case it was 9.0.0 for the Tesla and 5.0.0 for the GTX, so you will have to use **your IDs** for your use case, don't use mine!
Then I created an entry for each card, e.g.

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier     "Device0"
   Driver         "nvidia"
   VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
   BoardName      "Tesla"
   BusID          "PCI:9:0:0"
   Option         "Accel" "false"
   Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"
   Option "NoLogo" "true"
   Option "UseEDID" "false"
   Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
   Option "MultiGPU" "false"
EndSection
```

> Option "ProbeAllGpus" "boolean"
> Note that disabling this option may affect configurability through nvidia-settings, since the X driver will not know about GPUs that
> aren't currently being used or the display devices attached to them.
>
> Additionally, the special value "none" can be specified for the
> "UseDisplayDevice" option. When this value is given, any programming
> of the display hardware is disabled. The NVIDIA driver will not
> perform any mode validation or mode setting for this X screen. This is
> intended for use in conjunction with CUDA

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier     "Device1"
  Driver         "nvidia"
  VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
  BoardName      "GTX"
  BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection
```

And then on the "Screen" section, use just the "Device1" for the card or cards you want to use as video output, e.g.:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

In my case I have a multi-monitor setup connected to the GTX card, so it's a bit more elaborate than this, but it should give you a good starting point.

I'm still having trouble and trying to debug suspend/resume with this configuration.

Comment: I used this answer but didn't add all the extra options. I added the ` Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"` under the device I did not want to use, and adjusted the screen section to the Device I wanted  to use. Log out and log in and X started with the correct GPU.

Comment: You don't need to set `UseDisplayDevice` if your GPU is "headless", i.e. if it has no display outputs(e.g. Tesla P40) ([source](https://virtualgl.org/Documentation/HeadlessNV)). Also note that `lspci` shows PCI IDs in hexadecimal, so `43:00.0` in the output translates to `BusID "PCI:67:0:0"` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` since `0x43 == 67`.